# Microsoft BotBuilder Bot State API is deprecated. , Need Help in understanding the new Architecture

Tags: facebook, azure, bots, botframework

**Issue Description :-**

Ms bot builder bot code is throwing that the "Bot State API is deprecated ,Please refer to https://aka.ms/I6swrh for details on how to replace with your own storage."

I followed the documentation and its states that we can implement a custom state client using data storage platform of your choice instead of using Azure service . Can someone guide or provide some information in that direction how to achieve custom state client using local data storage.

So with this change the Microsoft web based connector use will be just a web based platform for conversion of Platform specific request to bot framework specific format and vice versa and state management will be handled locally .

**Environment Details :-**
SDK Platform: Node.js
SDK Version: 3.12.0
Active Channels: Facebook
Deployment Environment: ngrok

**Reproduction Steps :-**
update your bot builder SDK to 3.12.0 and observe your logs

Comment: By "local data storage" do you mean browser local storage, or node.js hosting site's local storage?

Comment: see if this reference helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48259153/microsoft-bot-builder-chat-bot-error/49079288#49079288

Answer (score 0):

They use [AzureBotStorage](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure/blob/master/Node/src/AzureBotStorage.ts) class in the sample which accepts [IStorageClient](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure/blob/0571e46159be56b725e23d87174465fd3a6de632/Node/src/IStorageClient.ts) interface. You implement this storage client for your favorite database and that's it.